# Specifying a wrapper in simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

When using the [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem, is it possible to specify a wrapper and its HTML? I don't want to manually create a `<div>` via HTML, but want to learn if there are `wrapper` options to pass into `simple_fields_for`.

Given

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :xxx, do |xxx| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I want the `simple_fields_for` to create a wrapper, `<div class="xyz">...</div>` around any code output inside it

Similar issues:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/929
- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/357
- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1440

Comment: Do you want the DIV inside or outside the form?

Comment: Inside the form. `simple_fields_for` is for a nested form, which is inside a parent form. I want the div to wrap this nested form.

Comment: Sorry I though you meant `simple_form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to create a method that wraps `simple_fields_for`.

```
# config/initializers/special_form_builder.rb
module SpecialFormBuilder
  def special_fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)
    super.simple_fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}) do
      content_tag :div, class: "xyz" do
        block.call
      end
    end
  end
end

module SimpleForm
  class FormBuilder
    include SpecialFormBuilder
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you make an example of how to consume this?

Comment: `f.special_fields_for :xxx, do |xxx|` - it just wraps the `simple_fields_for` method.

Comment: Its untested and I'm not 100% sure about the call signature for `simple_fields_for`. Thats the signature for `fields_for`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this issue and the given solution does not work, the problem is that the hidden id field is rendered outside of the wrapper element.

It seems that the problem is not simple_form, the problem is in rails within the [FormHelper#fields_for_nested_model](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0b3c710d35199d187dbfddaefbb9ab2752ea6498/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L2549) method.

Also, simple form accept a `wrapper` option on simple_form_for, but it defines the default wrapper used in the nested form inputs, not a wrapper for the form itself.

The only solution I see, is to use the option `include_id: false` and add the hidden field within the wrapper tag.